# How to make a method with @BeforeClass to run more than once?

Tags: testing, automation, testng

I wish to run a method with @BeforeClass annotation twice (or more). Is there a way to do so with TestNG?

Like: @Test(invocationCount = 2)?

Comment: You should add more description about your scenario with reference to use.

Comment: Are you looking for @BeforeMethod ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such provision available in TestNG.

`@BeforeClass` is a configuration method that is designed to run exactly once before any `@Test` methods within a particular class get executed.

So there's no way of altering its behavior.